# unable to set xlim and ylim using min() and max() in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am missing something crucial here and can't see it.

Why does min and max not work to set the axis limits?

```
mtcars %>%  
  select(mpg, cyl, disp, wt) %>% 
  filter(complete.cases(disp)) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x=mpg, y=disp, colour=cyl), size=3) +
  xlim(min(mpg, na.rm=TRUE),max(mpg, na.rm=TRUE)) +
  ylim(min(disp, na.rm=TRUE),max(disp, na.rm=TRUE)) +
  scale_colour_gradient(low="red",high="green", name = "cyl")
```

This works:

```
    mtcars %>%  
      select(mpg, cyl, disp, wt) %>% 
      filter(complete.cases(disp)) %>% 
      ggplot() +
      geom_point(aes(x=mpg, y=disp, colour=cyl), size=3) +
#      xlim(min(mpg, na.rm=TRUE),max(mpg, na.rm=TRUE)) +
#      ylim(min(disp, na.rm=TRUE),max(disp, na.rm=TRUE)) +
      scale_colour_gradient(low="red",high="green", name = "cyl")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ggplot cannot access the column values in the way that dplyr can.

You need to add in the data:

```
mtcars %>%  
  select(mpg, cyl, disp, wt) %>% 
  filter(complete.cases(disp)) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x=mpg, y=disp, colour=cyl), size=3) +
  xlim(min(mtcars$mpg, na.rm=TRUE),max(mtcars$mpg, na.rm=TRUE)) +
  ylim(min(mtcars$disp, na.rm=TRUE),max(mtcars$disp, na.rm=TRUE)) +
  scale_colour_gradient(low="red",high="green", name = "cyl")
```

Comment: The solution you posted will not take into account the filter passed before through the dplyr pipe.
How can one reference and use the subset of data passed to ggplot? For instance, if I want to use xlim as mean(mpg) ± 3*sd(mpg) ?

Answer (score 5):

You can't reference column names in `ggplot` objects except inside `aes()` and in a formula or `vars()` in a `facet_*` function. But the helper function `expand_scale` is there to help you expand the scales in a more controlled way.

For example:

```
# add 1 unit to the x-scale in each direction
scale_x_continuous(expand = expand_scale(add = 1))
# have the scale exactly fit the data, no padding
scale_x_continuous(expand = expand_scale(0, 0))
# extend the scale by 10% in each direction
scale_x_continuous(expand = expand_scale(mult = .1))
```

See `?scale_x_continuous` and especially `?expand_scale` for details. It's also possible to selectively pad just the top or just the bottom of each scale, there are examples in `?expand_scale`.