# How to programmatically label the minimum and maximum values on a `ggplot` axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis, axis-labels

I want to have **axis ticks** (`breaks`) for the **minimum** value and **maximum** value observed in the data. But I do not want to do this manually because the code should scale to different datasets.

I have tried adapting https://stackoverflow.com/a/22819926/17724015, https://stackoverflow.com/a/5380817/17724015, and https://stackoverflow.com/a/52337662/17724015. What `ggplot` options am I missing?

```r
# situation
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(x = sample(letters), y = 1:26)
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_y_reverse()
```

[image]

```r
# required output
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_y_reverse(breaks = c(1, 10, 20, 26))
```

[image]

```r
# attempted solution (not suitable, not enough breaks)
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_y_reverse(breaks = seq(min(dat$y), max(dat$y), by = mean(range(dat$y)) - 1))
```

[image]

```r
# attempted solution (not scalable, too many breaks)
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_y_reverse(n.breaks = nrow(dat) - 1)
```

[image]

```r
# attempted solution (not working)
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_y_reverse(expand = expansion(add = 1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default function for calculating breaks is `scales::extended_breaks()`. You can run that function and modify the results as you see fit. (And the `breaks` argument accepts a function.) Maybe something like this:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_y_reverse(breaks = \(y) {
    eb = scales::extended_breaks()(y)
    eb[1] = min(dat$y)
    eb[length(eb)] = max(dat$y)
    eb
  })
```

[image]

I'm not sure of a good way to avoid hardcoding the data frame and y column here, but at least it's better than hardcoding the actual values. Perhaps someone else will know how to do that.

Comment: I think you can just change `dat$y` to `y` if you want to avoid hard-coding.

Comment: Thanks for the thought @AllanCameron, but it doesn't work here. The `breaks` function's input is the limits, which are padded. So just using `y` makes the upper and lower breaks right at the padded limits, `-0.8` and `27.8`. And since `geom_tile` extends beyond the strict range of the data, even removing the padding with `expand = expansion(0, 0)` results in 0.5 and 26.5. (And moving the hard-coding from the breaks argument to `limits = rev(range(dat$y))` results in missing geoms on the extremes because of the tiles extending beyond the points.)

Comment: Thank you very much. The last bit of hardcoding may be of interest for future reference. But in my specific case, `dat$y` does not yield any problems because I'm using a wrapper function around the plot-generating part, so this resolves my issue.